Older horror movie - people trapped in a building
The movie is about some group of people trapped inside a bulding by some unknown force. Every their try to escape is somehow in vain. The building looks more like one large room. They try to cut the door with a saw but the guy doing it saws his hand off in distraction. Eventually they get to basement just to find some fantasy guy, I think dressed in white, who is responsible for them being trapped, he is some kind of a devil. In the end they kill him by stabbing (or something) his heart which was outside his body, kept somewhere else. Anyone have any idea?

Welcome to Movies & TV! We have a minimum standard for ID questions. Please try to add anything that may help identification. When was it released? Was it in Color or Black & White? What time period was it showing? What country was it likely from or what language was it in? Are there any other plot details you remember? Descriptions of scenes or names of characters or actors you can give? Feel free to [edit] any additional details into the question. For help writing a good identification question, see: Identify-This-X Questions.

Sorry about that. This was all I could remember, apart from probably being English speaking American movie. I was really young when I saw it on TV, no more than 5 years old and now I'm 32.

I believe the movie you're describing is a 1978 horror film, called The Evil and starring Richard Crenna, Joanna Pettet, Andrew Prine and Victor Buono. It is also known as House of Evil.

IMDB
Plot:
Wikipedia

Psychiatrist C.J. Arnold buys an abandoned mansion, which was built
  over hot sulfur pits, in order to set up a drug rehab center. He
  recruits a group of volunteers to help clean-up and renovate the large
  house. Almost immediately, C.J.'s wife, Dr. Caroline Arnold, starts
  sensing a strange and usual presence that starts to manifest as a
  ghostly apparition. Soon thereafter, more strange and eerie things
  start to happen which start to agitate the volunteers, along with the
  resident dog.
Later on, C.J. discovers a trap door in the basement, which he opens
  up and unknowingly unleashes a menacing spirit. Suddenly, all of the
  doors and windows become locked, trapping everyone inside the creepy
  mansion. They soon discover that the trap door in the basement is
  actually a gateway into hell. Slowly, the evil force within the house
  starts to kill off the trapped occupants one by one through a series
  of bizarre deaths.

stomptokyo

After a pep talk by Raymond, an attempt is made to cut through the
  front door with a radial saw, only to find it as tough as the windows.
  Raymond gets hyp-mo-tized and uses the saw on himself, nearly cutting
  off his hand.

The psychologist finds himself in a dazzlingly white room, population
  one: The Evil (Victor Buono) a kindly looking fat man dressed in
  white, sitting on a white throne.

Old Scratch's fun is cut short, however, when Carol pops up and stabs
  him with the cross.

Trailer: Youtube 

Yes that's the one! My god, after all these years, almost 30, I'll get to watch it again! Can't thank you enough!

Please, Put a check if the answer is  right. Thank you
